# Cross Domain Cookies with Angularjs, Nodejs, Expressjs, express-sessoion, and Mongo Store

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have a suite of programs that are all under the same company and I am trying to develop a single login / authentication service that can persist through  all of the programs. The idea is very micro-service oriented in which we will have one service to handle authentication and persist it as long as someone is in one of the programs. The issue is I need my other services to be able to access the same cookies across all of the domains and be able to send those cookies to the auth service for session verification. Please correct me if this is not the proper way to set up micro-services with a login/auth service.

For my front end (Angularjs):

```
  service.login = function (obj, callback) {
        $http.post(loginService + "login", obj, {
            withCredentials: true
        }).success(function (data) {
            callback(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers) {
            console.log(status);
        });
    };
```

For my server (Node, Express, Mongo):

```
var options = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('company.pfx'),
    passphrase: 'pass',
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('gd1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('gd2.crt'), fs.readFileSync('gd3.crt')],
    spdy: {
        protocols: ['h2', 'spdy/3.1', 'http/1.1'],
        plain: false,
        'x-forwarded-for': true,
        connection: {
            windowSize: 1024 * 1024, // Server's window size

            // **optional** if true - server will send 3.1 frames on 3.0 *plain* spdy
            autoSpdy31: false
        }
    }
};

var server = spdy.createServer(options, app);

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/static", express.static('static'));
app.use("/logins", express.static('logins'));
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy for production with a proxy server
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    genid: function (req) {
        return uuid.v4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    name: "myToken",
    secret: 'mysecret',
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: (45 * 60000) }, // set secure to true when in production
    store: new mongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://' + base + 'sessions' })
}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);//req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
    next();
});
```

Requesting:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var sess = req.session, token = req.cookies.myToken;
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

To test this I have a virtual machine running on my system with the application deployed and then I am also running my localhost:/ application. From my understanding my cookies should remain the same between the two calls with the same session if I have CORS set up properly. Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.domain') ?

Basically a wildcard matching any subdomain under your main domain.

Comment: Yes this works for sub-domains but my programs will be running on separate domains.